# WOPI Host in PHP - Not able to view file

Tags: php, ms-wopi

I have implemented APIs which are required for WOPI Host, as I am trying to solve Viewing doc problem right now, I implemented CheckFileInfo and GetFile endpoints only.

`/wopi/files/{fileId}`

```
$filePath = public_path('sample.docx');

$handle = fopen($filePath, "r");
$size = filesize($filePath);
$contents = fread($handle, $size);

return [
    "BaseFileName" => "sample.docx",
    "Size" => $size,
    "OwnerId" => 1,
    "UserId" => 1,
    "Version" => rand(),
    "FileUrl" => url("sample.docx")
];
```

`/wopi/files/{fileId}/contents`

```
$file = public_path('sample.docx');

return new BinaryFileResponse($file);
```

BinaryResponse is from - Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse

I have tried multiple implementations to return "the full binary contents of the file" (To satisfy this: https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/GetFile.html)

But I always end up with the following error.

[image]

Side Note: We registered with Cloud Storage Program of Microsoft, with domain www.**world.com, and I hosted the app at `test-wopi.**world.com`

Comment: Can I know, you are using Production Discovery URL or Test Discovery URL?

Comment: @SandunIsuruNiraj I am also facing a similar issue. what was the problem here?